Stop EF from populating navigation properties
I am trying to create an application that restores the entities for one environment by copying entities from another environment (direct database backup is not possible due to specific issues).
My problem is that when I retrieve a specific entity it automatically populates the navigation properties as well. This creates an issue when I restore a collection of entities that it runs into an error with another set of entities due to the entity in the navigation property being tracked already. Is it possible to stop EF core from populating navigation properties completely?
RestoreItem1s(updateData.Item1); //Goes fine
RestoreItem2s(updateData.Item2); //Exeption that instance cannot be tracked
RestoreItem3s(updateData.Item3);


Use AsNoTracking() then. Or periodically clear ChangeTracker - context.ChangeTracker.Clear().

Problem is that the entities in Item1 2 and 3 come from one dbcontext (hereby dbcontext_source) and are used to update/add entities of another dbcontext (hereby dbcontext_target). I could add SaveChanges between each RestoreItem step and clear the tracked entities that way. Will try that out.

You can't stop EF from populating navigation properties when related entities are attached to the context. That's relationship fixup and EF always performs it. For the rest it's hard to help without seeing more details.
